# Java: Filter large text file in parallel while maintaining order

Tags: java, text, parallel-processing, stream

Assuming that I have a very large file on a SSD, and 48 cores.
I want to filter the text file (line based text file), and leave certain sentences only. Then I want to write the filtered content to a new file, while maintaining the original order.

I think that Java parallel streams will not keep the order.

What I had in mind is something like this: create 48 points that split the file evenly, then adjust the pointers to start in new lines, then create 48 threads that each process different chunk and filter the lines (and save the result in memory - the result is much smaller than the original files), and then take the 48 pieces and write them to one file, one after another.

Is this the right approach, and is there a Java framework for it, or should it be written from scratch?

Comment: Sounds like you're overcomplicating this to me - can you not just use a plain reader, go through the file line by line (or chunk by chunk if it's not separate by line breaks), then filter and write the new file as you go? Why the need for separate threads - is there a particular performance requirement you're working to?

Comment: @MichaelBerry yes, the idea is to try speed up things by utilizing the available cores.

Comment: In order to help here we'll need details of how big the file is, how long it's taking currently, and profiling information that shows what the current bottlenecks are. If the bottleneck is IO, then there's not really anything more that can be done, aside from using RAID0 or similar to stripe the disks to get more throughput.

Comment: I maintain an open source data parallel product that has a built-in function that supports what you want. See here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse/

Answer (score 0):

In this particular context working in a multithread environment doesn't increase your performances.

You are doing heavy IO operations (read and write to disk) that can't be done by different threads.

You can surely parallelize the search once you loaded your content and before writing it to disk, but for a normal text search the speed can't be really increased.

Consider that before trying to apply a complex multithreading algorythm:

- The coding time depends on IO operations? (network, disk, database...)

If yes and the calculus are not heavy is not a good idea to spend a lot of time trying to speed up the calculus phase because IO operations happens at hundred or tousands of time slower than in memory operations.

---

By the way try to split the execution time in the following parts:

- load the file in memory
- search the phrases
- write the result to disk

If the second phase is really faster compared to the others parallelizing is not a good solution, but you have to try other solutions.